# how to get variable value from asterisk with asternet

Tags: c#, asterisk, asteriskami, dialplan, asternet

I use the `asterNet` for manage event IN `asterisk`.

I need to get value of variable (`result`) in c# from `dialplan` query.

```
exten => test,1, NoOp(************ test ****************);
same => n,Answer();
same => n,Playback(hellow-world);
same => n,set(result=123456);
same => n,Hangup();
```

I used the following query to get `result` variable:

```
private string GetVar(string channel)
{
    string result = "";
    try
    {
        var gv = new GetVarAction(channel, "result");
        ManagerResponse mr = manager.SendAction(gv);
        result = mr.Attributes["result"];
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     { }
     return result;
}
```

but is's encounter with this error:

> timeout waiting for response to originate

I searched the web but did not find anything useful.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You have read source code. You also can use TCPDUMP command on linux to see how it really go via socket. Please also note, that channel will not exists exactly after Hangup. And no delay between.

Comment: thx @arheops, can i use the `AGI` for return the variable value? if `yes`, have a example code?

Comment: Yes, you can. I saw no article about AGI without example of how to get variable.

Comment: What do you want to do with the results? To get it with AGI you need to listen to agi and enter the agi from the dialplan. When do you want to access the variable?

Comment: hi @Shloime Rosenblum, I need to result in `c#` environment to save in database. This code snippet is simplified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the results with AGI.

You need to setup FastAGI with Asternet and then you can get the results to save to you DB.

To setup FastAGI you need to set the script to the specific class where you will handle the call and start the FastAGI service from you programs `Main` method in `program.cs`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        AsteriskFastAGI agi = new AsteriskFastAGI();
        

        agi.MappingStrategy = new GeneralMappingStrategy(new List<ScriptMapping>()
        {
            new ScriptMapping() {
                ScriptClass = "MyNamespace.GetResult",
                ScriptName = "getresult"
            }

        });

        agi.Start();
}
```

and create a class `GetResult` which inherits `AGIScript` where you will handle the call inside the `Service` method and use the `GetVariable` function to get the variable content

```
namespace MyNamespace
{     
    class GetResult : AGIScript
    {
         public override void Service(AGIRequest request, AGIChannel channel)
         {    
            try
            {
                string result = GetVariable("result")
                //save to DB
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and you need to enter the agi from your dialplan. If the c# program is running on the same server as asterisk you can do localhost `same => n,agi(agi://localhost/getresult)` or put your server's local ip address `same => n,agi(agi://xxx.xxx.x.x/getresult)` and if the c# program is running on a remote server put the remote server ip address `same => n,agi(agi://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/getresult)` and make sure that your asterisk server public ip is open in the remote server's firewall.

```
exten => test,1, NoOp(************ test ****************);
same => n,Answer();
same => n,Playback(hellow-world);
same => n,set(result=123456);
same => n,agi(agi://yourserverip/getresult)
same => n,Hangup();
```

Comment: thx @Shloime Rosenblum, I tried this solution but couldn't get an answer, can you complete example `Agi` Dialplan code?, please.

Comment: Is the c# program running on the same server as asterisk? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: `c#` program running on `192.168.1.2` and `asterisk` server run at `192.168.1.126`. when I run `agi.Start();` program is hanging without error. what is the `MyNamespace`? is my `c#` namespace? Where should I put and calling `AGIScript ` script?

Comment: of course, I used the `windows desktop` application. not `web` application.

Comment: Yes your program is listening to the requests from asterisk. The best way is a console application. You should put your c# namespace of the class that has the service method. You should put in your dialplan `same => n,agi(agi://192.168.1.2/getresult)`

Comment: the agi script should be in a separate class it can be anywhere in the program but you must map it in the main method with the full namespace and class name. `AGIScript` is a base class that needs to be inherited on the script class like above. When the dialplan enters the program it will call the service method. Make sure that Asternet is referenced in the project

Comment: thx @ShloimeRosenblum, I tested but not working. this is the log of asterisk: `AGI Rx << VERBOSE "No script configured for URL 'agi://192.168.1.2/getresult' (script 'getresult')"`. is this working in the `windows Desktop` application?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252878/discussion-between-shloime-rosenblum-and-aminrostami).

Comment: @hloimeRosenblum, can u help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77421028