# dialplan show the unicode char

Tags: asterisk, agi, dialplan, asternet

I have s simple code:

```
exten => p111,1, NoOp(********** test unicode char ************);
same => n,Answer();
same => n,Set(myVariable="امین رستمی")
same => n,NoOp(******** #2 ${myVariable}***************);
same => n,Hangup();
```

when I set the `myVariable` with unicode character, it's displayed `???? ?????`.
how to fix this?

### update----------------

I read the name of the contact from the database using the value of the `caller-id` (with `agi` in `Asternet`) and set the value in the `caller-id-name`, but in the output `????` it shows.

But when I use `asterisk's phonebook`, it displays the `unicode value` correctly.

How to fix unicode `caller-id-name`?

what's the difference between Initialization of variables?

Comment: You don't.  Caller ID is strictly ASCII.  Caller ID devices are primitive.

Comment: Large parts of the Asterisk codebase are from 20 years ago; it's unlikely they're going to handle unicode properly. Also you're not providing any detail here; how are you trying to display it? Have you accounted for settings in your database/terminal/whatever output you're using?

Comment: I'm not talking about the variable name.  I'm talking about the variable contents.  You CANNOT use Arabic characters in a caller ID.  You can't use anything outside of ASCII, because that's what the protocol uses.

Comment: Sure you can. You can use ANYTHING. Just need decode on end-user devices. Some systems(most known is ViciDial) are using that field for pass base64-encoded additional data.

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk do nothign with callerid name. Yes, it is unlikely support for UTF-8 in asterisk. But there are some devices was even 10 years ago which DO support UTF-8.

Support for charset should be just enabled on end-user devices. Asterisk not care if callerid is unreadable in ASCII.

I can't say about Arabic,but for there are some devices that support that for Cyrilic.

Your phonebook is web, it just knows how to use UTF-8. Your phone does not. That is difference.

Comment: thx @arheops, I test with `zoiper soft phone` but it's show `??????`, but when i add the number to the `phonebook's asterisks`, it's shows well. what is the  `phonebook's asterisks` unicode?

Comment: Sorry, you have figure that yourself. Have zero interest in Arabic alphabet.